# Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.4

Tags: android, gradle

### I just migrated gradle from 3.0.1 to 4.4. Now Android Studio showing gradle build failed showing below errors.

> Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionNotFoundException: Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.4.
>   Searched in the following locations:
>   https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.4/gradle-4.4.pom
>   https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.4/gradle-4.4.jar    https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.4/gradle-4.4.pom   https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.4/gradle-4.4.jar

Project level build.gradle file is following below

```
 buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        //classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        //replaced by 4.4 below
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.4'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Project structure is shown below.

[image: Project Structure and gradle setting]

Answer (score 58):

You mixed up with plugin version and `distributionUrl`. Plugin version should be `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'` or `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0`. Read [Android Plugin for Gradle Release Notes](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html#3-1-0).

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    }
}
```

And `distributionUrl` to `GradleWrapper`.

```
distributionUrl = https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip
```

Currently latest Version 3 gradle plugin available on android for which you have to use  `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'`.
To be up to date see [Configure Your Build](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/index.html).

Comment: And then when you change the gradle plugin to 3.1.0, if you see "Could not find org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre8:1.2.0" and "Required by:
    project :app > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:3.1.0", check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49534872/after-update-to-android-studio-3-1-im-facing-this-erorr-could-not-find-org-jetb for some ideas what to do.

Comment: Check the http address for the distributionUrl in a browser (leaving off the zip file name at the end). Your distributionUrl is in {project folder}\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.propterties

Comment: The latest plugin version is now at [`4.1.0`](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#4-1-0) instead of `3.1.x` and the `distributionUrl` should be at [`6.8.x`](https://gradle.org/releases/).

Comment: @BrianLi did you get this error too.. I updated my android studio and I have been stuck with "Cause: unable to find valid certification path to requested target" error since yesterday

Comment: I haven't had that issue yet, will let you know if I come across it

Answer (score 6):

Guess you mixed up [Gradle](https://gradle.org/releases/) and [Android Gradle Plugin](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#updating-gradle) regarding their versions?

The latest Android Gradle Plugin is v4.0.0 as of April 2020, which maps to Gradle v6.1.1.