# Gradle Error : Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:6.6.1

Tags: android

I'm trying to build my android project, but I've got this error :

```
Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:6.6.1.
```

Searched in the following locations:

- https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/6.6.1/gradle-6.6.1.pom
  If the artifact you are trying to retrieve can be found in the repository but without metadata in 'Maven POM' format, you need to adjust the 'metadataSources { ... }' of the repository declaration.
  Required by:
  project :
  Add Google Maven repository and sync project
  Open File

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49505245/could-not-find-com-android-tools-buildgradle4-4)

Answer (score 12):

**Gradle version** and **gradle plugin version** are different things. Gradle version 6.6.1 **exist** but gradle plugin version 6.6.1 **does not exist**. You need to update gradle plugin version as 4.0.2 in your app level build.gradle file.

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.2'
}
```

You can find more information from https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin

Answer (score 1):

You need to check these two files.

[image]

[image]