# Android Build Gradle

Tags: android

I have a problem in developing Android Studio.
It gives me this error:

Could not find gradle-4.0.1.jar (com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1).
Searched in the following locations:
https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.0.1/gradle-4.0.1.jar

I thought maybe it is because of proxy settings but there's no connection problem.
can anybody help me about this problem?
Thank you so much!

Comment: I think thik question is already answered here... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49505245/could-not-find-com-android-tools-buildgradle4-4/49505321

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1 OR 4.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63157065/could-not-find-com-android-tools-buildgradle4-0-1-or-4-0-0)

Comment: Can you update the question with your build.gradle(app) code. This kind of error is to do something with "classpath" inside dependencies.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63157065/could-not-find-com-android-tools-buildgradle4-0-1-or-4-0-0/63235324#63235324